# Windows 11 IoT in Kiosk mode FORCE allow web cam access

Tags: windows, webcam, windows-11, kiosk, kiosk-mode

We have a Kiosk machine configured with Windows 11 IoT Enterprise running in Kiosk mode and everything is good. Windows creates specific Kiosk user to run in Kiosk mode which will start Edge browser and load our app. The app needs access to the webcam attached to the Kiosk so that it can do QR code scanning and face recognition.

The issue we are having is that every time the app needs access to the webcam it asks the users permission if they would like to Allow access to webcam (through a small pop-up on the top left hand side corner of the browser). The user can either 'Allow' or 'Deny' access.

Ideally, we don't want our end users to see this pop-up as we would like to 'force' allow the app access to the web cam without keep asking permission from the end users (it just does not add up to a great user experience in a Kiosk mode).

We have searched and tried few ideas we found online about changing REG keys and Local Policy settings but non of them seem to work when Windows starts in 'Kiosk' mode. They work for normal Windows users (like local users or admin users) but not for the Kiosk user.

Any help, suggestions, recommendations would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. I hope this will help anyone else facing the same issue.

I had to create new key in the Windows 11 IoT registry under the following structure:

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge\VideoCatpureAllowedUrls
```

After you create the key above, I then added new String value of '1' so the Reg path looks like this"

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge\VideoCatpureAllowedUrls\1
```

Then I double clicked on the 1 and added the value of my app URL which needs access to the web cam. For example:

```
https://www.myapp.com/
```

Restart my Windows 11 IoT which booted in Kiosk mode and I was able to access the web cam via my web app without getting the popup asking me to 'Allow' or 'Deny' access.

[this site helped me alot](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-enable-or-disable-audio-video-and-screen-capture-in-edge)